# How to update a column value in datatype timestamp using Oracle 10G

Tags: sql, oracle10g, oracle-xe

While add a a column in update_time using datatype timestamp

So I need to update a timestamp value when I update the data using Oracle 10G in SQL Command Line

```
SQL> ALTER TABLE TIME_STAMPTABLE ADD UPDATE_TIME TIMESTAMP 
           DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

But I'm getting:

> ERROR at line 1:
>   ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option

Comment: Oracle just [doesn't support that syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_3001.htm#i2054940). You'll have to use a trigger to set the column value automatically during an update.

Comment: Where in the [Oracle 10g manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/toc.htm) did you find `on update current_timestamp`?

Comment: @Horse..I guess OP picked up the alter syntax from DB2 and tried his luck in oracle.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Alex, oracle does not support such syntax, you need to create a trigger shown below on you table.

```
SQL> ALTER TABLE TIME_STAMPTABLE ADD UPDATE_TIME TIMESTAMP ;

SQL> create or replace trigger upd_tim_stmp
before INSERT OR UPDATE on TIME_STAMPTABLE 
for each row
begin
:new.UPDATE_TIME:= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
end;
 /
```